# Lazy Script (Using Text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a script that does the same function as lazy, but with text?

> When user scroll down { show div with the text }

This script is to inscreave the page speed of my "news pages", because has too many characters.

```
  The IDEA:    When element is on screen { show:div }
    If not { Don't display the div }
```

***`The elements can't be loaded with the page, only when the user "scroll down".`***

If it's possible, can I add one fade in animation too?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about a feature like infinite scroll, but it's ambiguous

Comment: try javascript/jquery to show the div when you reach at position by scrolling.. post the code here if you face any problem with the code!